# In production mode, getting unknown error in angular 13 for http client post request

Tags: angular, post, httpclient

I am using Angular 13 and RxJS. I tried using observables and promises for angular POST request. also I have tried simple http POST in Angular. Everything works fine in dev mode but when i run the same in production I get "Unknown Error Occurred", which is strange. Also, under the network tab, I do not see any network call hitting the server, Network tab is empty. In my console, I get the error.

Below is my simple code:

```
this.httpClient.post(url, {username:this.username,password:this.password}).subscribe(res => console.log(JSON.stringify(res)));
```

Comment: What does your url look like? Can you show the code where you assign the url?

Comment: let url =  API_END_POINTS.API_USER ;
(which is something like, url = http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8060/api/login)

Comment: Ok. Does your REST API work properly? Did you try to make the post request with Postman, curl, etc.?

Comment: yes, the REST API sends correct response using Postman client @CarlitosJan

Comment: Don't you get any other error message? On the console? Or terminal? Maybe it could be a CORS Policy problem. Or maybe add the correct headers to your post request (for json format)

Comment: no, there is no other error message other than this unknown error occurred, which is making this debugging very hard.